# Paired experiment with trinomial response - Analysis help!

Tags: mixed-model, ordinal-data, paired-data

I'm looking to analyze data (in SAS) from a trial investigating the effect of a particular protective padding on preventing skin irritation at multiple body locations among spinal surgery patients.

*(i.e. "Is Tx1 associated with lower risk of outcome-Y, relative to Tx0/no-treatment?")*

There are **N=50** patients, each of whom had **three(3)** pads applied to one knee, one hip and one shoulder (exposed/Tx side), while the opposite knee/hip/shoulder was left bare (unexposed/non-Tx side). (Right vs. Left side was randomized.)
Following surgery, patients were assessed for skin damage, and categorized **ordinally** into "None", "Redness/Bruising", and "Skin tear." (This could also be collapsed into a **dichotomous** outcome.)

**Summary:** N=50 pts, 6 locations on each pt (3 "exposed", 3 "unexposed"), with a tri-ordinal (1,2,3) OR dichotomous (0,1) outcome *assessed for each location*.

...I'm not all that experienced with analyzing correlated data, and am having trouble figuring out the most appropriate method. Hoping someone here can help point me in the right direction! Any suggestions on methods or resources (books, articles, blogs, etc.) would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a small dataset, & in particular can be represented by a contingency table.  Can you post it?

Comment: @gung Unfortunately I do not have the data set yet, I'm just trying to plan ahead. But yes, it is small, particularly given that I suspect the majority (80%-90%?) will be negative for bruising/tears. I'll post once I have a cleaned dataset though...